# Как вставить пробелы?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть текст в RichTextBox, мне надо чтоб считывались все пробелы(если у меня 2 пробела, то они не считывались как один). Это мне надо для выравнивания текста по ширине, в программе оно выглядит коряво.
Пример: есть текст "01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49", сам элемент RichTextBox такого размера, что этот текст выглядит как массив 7х7. Мне надо чтоб цифры располагались дальше чем на один пробел, если применить выравнивание, то все выглядит как надо, за исключением последней строки.

Comment: В свойствах RichTextBox настройки покрутите, там их много про выравнивание, например TextWrap.. чего то там, на память не вспомнить, в любом случае читать должен 2 пробела, если их там два. Шрифт может какой с ровным соотношением керинга выбрать, типа systemsys, console итд

Comment: @NewView TextWrap дает возможность переноса текста в TextBox и он встроен автоматически в RichTextBox

Comment: ВОПРОС БОЛЕЕ НЕ АКТУАЛЕН... xml:space="preserve"